# Podio: Can I set a reminder on a date field through the API/SDK?

Tags: ios, podio

I've got an app in Podio that represents Meetings. One of the fields is time/date and it allows a reminder to be set for that time/date (much like you can with tasks).

I've also got an iOS app that can create Meeting items and I was hoping there was a way to programatically create a reminder when the item is created (or that a workflow could be created to handle it) but it doesn't seem to be possible. The Reminders API only works for tasks, according to the documentation, and there doesn't seem to be another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be missing in documentation, but reminders should also work for items.

Please try to create one using details from here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/reminders/create-or-update-reminder-3315055 and use `item` as `ref_type` and your item id as `ref_id`

Comment: You're right! Works great! It's a shame I can only have one reminder for an item, would be nice to setup multiple reminders at 10, 5 and 0 minutes before. Maybe I can figure out a way to make use of the snooze functionality!

Comment: Info on that is here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/reminders/snooze-reminder-3321049 :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, I've also updated Podio documentation to include `item` ref_type